# Google web fonts not working in Express

Tags: node.js, express, google-webfonts

I'm having trouble getting Google webfonts to work in express 3.0.

Loading the font in the standard way doesn't seem to work:

```
link(href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crete+Round')
```

however loading the font in one of these ways works fine:

```
    script(type="text/javascript")
        WebFontConfig = {google: { families: [ 'Crete+Round::latin' ] }};
        (function() {
            var wf = document.createElement('script');
            wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
            wf.type = 'text/javascript';
            wf.async = 'true';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
        })();
```

or

```
    style
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crete+Round);
```

Comment: Weird... could it be another new "feature" of express 3. I've done this a few time in express 2 with no problem. What is the html output ? do you get anything thing weird ?

Comment: Does it work if you add the `rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'` attributes to the `link` tag? As long as Express is outputting the HTML that you expect it to (check the source), then it's not an Express/Jade issue.

Comment: @3on Yes I haven't had any problems in express 2

Comment: @BrandonTilley I added rel and type and it fixed the problem. Strange, I didn't think those were necessary in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues with Express 3.0.0rc2 not including CSS. I'm not sure if this is a Jade or an Express issue, but when I add a working `style.css` it works just fine like so:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
```

Yet, if I remove that line and insert, say Twitter Bootstrap css files, I get weird HTML output.

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

It only works if I have something like this:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
```

Why? I know not. :-) I assume it's something to do with the parsing and HTML output.